# JavaFX button with svg shape still has rectangular clickable area

Tags: css, javafx

I want to make a button with a shape of svg format and i have written the CSS code below:

```
.button {

    -fx-background-color: #44c553;
    -size: 100px;
    -fx-min-height: -size;
    -fx-min-width: -size;
    -fx-max-height: -size;
    -fx-max-width: -size;
    -fx-shape: "m207.10955,279.95363l101.61276,-154.83848l101.61276,154.83848l-203.22552,0z" ;
}
```

the problem is that when i hover mouse on button i can press it from outside of its shape because the button borders are still rectangular. how can i make the button not clickable from outside of its shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node` has the [`pickOnBounds` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#pickOnBoundsProperty):

> Defines how the picking computation is done for this node when triggered by a `MouseEvent` or a `contains` function call. If `pickOnBounds` is true, then picking is computed by intersecting with the bounds of this node, else picking is computed by intersecting with the geometric shape of this node.

This property has a default value of `false`, which is what you want. However, the `Region` class sets this property to `true` in its only [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#%3Cinit%3E()):

> Creates a new Region with an empty Background and and empty Border. The Region defaults to having pickOnBounds set to true, meaning that any pick (mouse picking or touch picking etc) that occurs within the bounds in local of the Region will return true, regardless of whether the Region is filled or transparent.

Since `Button` is a subclass of `Region` it also has its `pickOnBounds` property set to `true`. In order to have the behavior you want you'll need to set this property back to `false`. Unfortunately, `pickOnBounds` doesn't seem settable from CSS; meaning you'll need to set it from code or FXML.